# Android emulator problem

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

Whenever I click on a button it does nothing here is some code (I use Log.d() and found the execution stopped at right before setContentView(R.layout.play) :

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
        switch( v.getId()){
        case R.id.play:
            setContentView(R.layout.play);
            setQuestion();
        case R.id.level:
            setContentView(R.layout.level);
            if(lvl=="1") {
                lvl1.setChecked(true);
            }
            if(lvl=="2") {
                lvl2.setChecked(true);
            }
            if(lvl=="3") {
                lvl3.setChecked(true);
            }
            if(lvl=="4") {
                lvl4.setChecked(true);
            }
            if(lvl=="5") {
                lvl5.setChecked(true);
            }
            setContentView(R.layout.level);

        case R.id.setLevel:
            if(lvl1.isChecked()) {
                setLevel("1");
            }
            if(lvl2.isChecked()) {
                setLevel("2");
            }
            if(lvl3.isChecked()) {
                setLevel("3");
            }
            if(lvl4.isChecked()) {
                setLevel("4");
            }
            if(lvl5.isChecked()) {
                setLevel("5");
            }







        }
    }
```

When i click the level button it does nothing!

logact:

```
03-19 00:11:57.708: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
03-19 00:12:11.897: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
03-19 00:12:15.643: ERROR/BatteryService(67): usbOnlinePath not found
03-19 00:12:15.643: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryVoltagePath not found
03-19 00:12:15.658: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryTemperaturePath not found
03-19 00:12:15.751: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(67): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
03-19 00:12:26.218: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
03-19 00:12:26.238: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
03-19 00:12:26.747: ERROR/System(67): Failure starting core service
03-19 00:12:26.747: ERROR/System(67): java.lang.SecurityException
03-19 00:12:26.747: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
03-19 00:12:26.747: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
03-19 00:12:26.747: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
03-19 00:12:26.747: ERROR/System(67):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
03-19 00:12:28.257: ERROR/VoldConnector(67): No connection to daemon
03-19 00:12:28.257: ERROR/VoldConnector(67): java.lang.IllegalStateException
03-19 00:12:28.257: ERROR/VoldConnector(67):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:191)
03-19 00:12:28.257: ERROR/VoldConnector(67):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.sendCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:178)
03-19 00:12:28.257: ERROR/VoldConnector(67):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:213)
03-19 00:12:28.257: ERROR/VoldConnector(67):     at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.doListCommand(NativeDaemonConnector.java:258)
03-19 00:12:28.257: ERROR/VoldConnector(67):     at com.android.server.MountService$2.run(MountService.java:425)
03-19 00:12:29.322: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-19 00:12:29.338: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-19 00:12:29.347: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-19 00:12:29.411: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-19 00:12:29.427: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-19 00:13:31.174: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
03-19 00:13:43.834: ERROR/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
03-19 00:13:46.234: ERROR/BatteryService(67): usbOnlinePath not found
03-19 00:13:46.234: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryVoltagePath not found
03-19 00:13:46.234: ERROR/BatteryService(67): batteryTemperaturePath not found
03-19 00:13:46.284: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(67): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
03-19 00:13:57.094: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
03-19 00:13:57.104: ERROR/EventHub(67): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
03-19 00:13:57.475: ERROR/System(67): Failure starting core service
03-19 00:13:57.475: ERROR/System(67): java.lang.SecurityException
03-19 00:13:57.475: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
03-19 00:13:57.475: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
03-19 00:13:57.475: ERROR/System(67):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
03-19 00:13:57.475: ERROR/System(67):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
03-19 00:13:59.354: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
03-19 00:13:59.374: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
03-19 00:13:59.404: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
03-19 00:13:59.413: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
03-19 00:13:59.413: ERROR/SoundPool(67): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
03-19 00:14:04.984: ERROR/ThrottleService(67): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
03-19 00:14:07.064: ERROR/logwrapper(147): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-19 00:14:07.135: ERROR/logwrapper(149): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
03-19 00:14:07.204: ERROR/logwrapper(150): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: can we get a little more code than that? also the errors from `logcat`?

Comment: hi can you tell me what is lvl here ? is it textview or edittext or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

Since Strings are objects, you should not compare Strings with `==`. Instead, you should use `lvl.equals("2")`.

Also, finish each case with `break;` statement. otherwise the code below your case will be executed too.

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Can you add some debug prints into the switch block, so we'll see if it enters there at all?

Comment: Sorry, um.... what are debug prints?

Comment: You can add lines to the output of log cat by using Log.d() method (see more here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) it is just another method that when executed will print a line to logcat(in your case), so if you add such prints in your methods, you'll know that you got to this line in the execution of your program. if you use it correct, you can also get a useful information about the state of your program at that line.

Comment: Edited my post showed where the execution stops!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things I notice.

1) You have no `break;` statements at the end of the each `case:`. Did you intend for the execution to flow from `R.id.play` to `R.id.level` to `R.id.setLevel`?

2) You call `setContentView(R.layout.level);` at the beginning of the `R.id.level` case and just before the `R.id.setLevel` case. One call is what I've seen. Is there a reason for two calls? I think the second call may reset any of your changes.